# What is the best way to prepare myself for playing trumpet in a musical?

Tags: trumpet, musical-theatre

I am a grade 4 trumpeter and am preparing to play in our school musical "Our House" (inspired by the band Madness). We are peforming this on 3 consecutive evenings and in the afternoon of the first day as well. I think the running time is about 2 hours. What advice would you have as to how I can make sure I don't run out of stamina?

Comment: Good question. To get the best answers, consider editing to tell more about the length of the show, about how much time the trumpet spends playing, and how often you'll be putting it on within what time frame (e.g. 9 times in a week, or just 2 shows on 2 days). Also, read about [how to avoid overly open-ended questions](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask); it might be best to focus on stamina and not just a "discussion prompt" for anything that might occur to people.

Comment: Won't there be rehearsals for the orchestra before the opening night? Don't overdo your normal personal practice and assess how things go in rehearsals.

Comment: How much time do hou spend practicing, rehearsing, and performing now?  How much playing will you be doing during the course of the show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start practicing TODAY for an hour every day.   An hour of concentrated practice is a lot more notes than you'll be playing over a 2 hour show!

Or perhaps you're used to playing in a marching band?   If you can handle half-a-dozen Sousa marches back-to back, you'll be OK for a show!

Here's the part.  Enjoy!

https://vdocuments.mx/our-house-trumpet.html

Comment: But beware the warnings at https://music.stackexchange.com/q/132910/78419